# SQL - Getting Percent Difference from dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a dynamic stored procedure that takes every month in my database and averages out the values per day.

What I currently have (values are the overall average for that month):

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | CustName | 201501 | 201502 | 201503 | 201504 | ..|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 32 | CustOne  | 5852.25| 5847.50| 6542.98| 7585.25| ..|
| 56 | CustTwo  | 5452.45| 7852.50| 6985.41| 1245.21| ..|
| 89 | CustThree| 8520.25| 7410.01| 9630.36| 1245.32| ..|
| .. | ...      |   ..   |   ..   |   ..   |   ..   | ..|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is the stored procedure I'm using to create the above table:

```
DECLARE @Dates NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Dates = CONCAT(@Dates + ', ', QUOTENAME(BalMonth))
FROM vAvgMonBal
GROUP BY BalMonth
ORDER BY BalMonth;

DECLARE @DynSQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @months NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @months = 'CONCAT( CONVERT(nvarchar(15), YEAR(BalDate)) , IIF(LEN(MONTH(BalDate)) > 1, CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(BalDate)), ''0'' + CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(BalDate)))) AS BalMonth'
SET @DynSQL = 'SELECT *
           FROM
               (SELECT 
                    a1.IDNbr, 
                    a2.CustName, ' + @months + ',
                    AVG(a1.Balance) as Balance
                FROM tblID a1 
                INNER JOIN tblCust a2 ON (a1.IDNbr = a2.IDNbr)
                WHERE a2.CustType != ''Inactive''
                GROUP BY 
                    a1.IDNbr, a2.CustName, CONCAT( CONVERT(nvarchar(15), YEAR(BalDate)) , IIF(LEN(MONTH(BalDate)) > 1, CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(BalDate)), ''0'' + CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(BalDate))))) as d1
PIVOT (
AVG(Balance)
FOR BalMonth IN (' + @Dates + ')
) piv';


EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynSQL
```

**Question**: how can I take the data from the previous stored procedure and get the percent difference, `(Month1/Month2) * 100`, from it like shown below? I'm expecting I'll need a new stored procedure or add on to the one I currently have.

What I'm needing (where each "`PerDiff`" is the percent difference of the previous month from the before table example):

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | CustName | PerDiff1 | PerDiff2 | PerDiff3 | PerDiff4 | ..|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 32 | CustOne  |  100.00  |   68.12  |  654.25  |  483.36  | ..|
| 56 | CustTwo  |   58.21  |  154.54  |  932.45  |   58.45  | ..|
| 89 | CustThree|  965.25  |  951.58  |  689.12  |   32.50  | ..|
| .. | ...      |   ....   |   ....   |   ....   |   ....   | ..|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've attempted to use something like:

```
DECLARE @PerDiff nvarchar(max);

SET @PerDiff = 'SELECT *
FROM (' + @DynSQL + ')'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @PerDiff
```

To at least try and get the data moving.

I'm no longer getting any error messages-- I'm generally just stuck on how to proceed with getting the math to be applied dynamically.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT1:** Here is the result of finalized @DynSQL

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT a1.DDANbr, 
a2.CustName, 
CONCAT( CONVERT(nvarchar(15), YEAR(BalDate)) , IIF(LEN(MONTH(BalDate)) > 1, CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(BalDate)), '0' + CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(BalDate))))AS BalMonth,
a1.Balance

FROM tblID a1 INNER JOIN tblCust a2 ON (a1.IDNbr = a2.IDNbr)

WHERE a2.CustType != 'Inactive'

GROUP BY a1.IDNbr, a2.CustName, BalDate, a1.Balance
) as d1
PIVOT (
AVG(Balance)
FOR BalMonth IN ([201501], [201502], [201503], [201504], [201505], [201506], [201507], [201508], [201509], [201510], [201511], [201512], [201601], [201602], [201603], [201604], [201605], [201606], [201607], [201608], [201609], [201610], [201611], [201612], [201701], [201702], [201703], [201704], [201705], [201706], [201707], [201708], [201709], [201710], [201711], [201712], [201801], [201802], [201803], [201804], [201805], [201806], [201807], [201808], [201809])
) piv
```

Answer (score 1):

When you take a query and make it a derived table, you have to give that table an alias.

Like this:

```
DECLARE @PerDiff nvarchar(max);

SET @PerDiff = 'SELECT IDNbr, CustName, ' + @months + '
FROM (' + @DynSQL + ') t1'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynSQL, @PerDiff
```

Comment: Ah. That gets rid of that error. Thank you! Though, I'm now getting `The parameters supplied for the batch are not valid`. Would this mean my `SELECT` statement?

Comment: `EXECUTE sp_executesql @PerDiff`, try using this instead of what you have.

Comment: @Tigerjz32 , thanks for the tip! It now states `multi-part identifier 'a1.BalDate' could not be bound." Removing the `a1.` then gives me "Invalid column name 'BalDate'". My guess for this one would be because I have an `INNER JOIN` and the fields are needing to be assigned to the proper tables?

Comment: The issue is in your `GROUP BY` clause. You cannot simply say `a1.BalDate` you have to include the whole string that creates `a1.BalDate`. I would suggest you break it out of dynamic SQL and make sure it runs first, then add it back as dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Tigerjz32, runs like a charm on its own. What do you mean by "the whole string that creates `a1.BalDate`" ?

Comment: Change the `a1.BalDate` to `CONCAT( CONVERT(nvarchar(15), YEAR(a1.BalDate)) , IIF(LEN(MONTH(a1.BalDate)) > 1, CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(a1.BalDate)), ''0'' + CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(a1.BalDate))))` in `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Tigerjz32 , Hmm. Doesn't change the output and still gives the error.

Comment: Could you please change this `EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynSql ` to `print @DynSQL` and send the output?

Comment: @Symon verify that you do in fact have a column named `BalDate` in the table named `TlbID`.   Make sure there's no typo in either of those names.

Comment: @Tigerjz32 , I have added the output of `Print @DynSQL`. And as per Tab's comment, yes I do have a `BalDate` column in `tblID`.

Comment: This does work, and shows me that I'm able to test my output. However, this doesn't quite answer the question of how I'd be able to get the `Percent Difference` as stated in the question. This did get rid of my error, though!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Dates NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Dates = CONCAT(@Dates + ', ', QUOTENAME(BalMonth))
FROM vAvgMonBal
GROUP BY BalMonth
ORDER BY BalMonth;

DECLARE @DynSQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @months NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @months = 'CONCAT( CONVERT(nvarchar(15), YEAR(BalDate)) , IIF(LEN(MONTH(BalDate)) > 1, CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(BalDate)), ''0'' + CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(BalDate)))) AS BalMonth'
SET @DynSQL = 'SELECT *
               FROM
                   (SELECT 
                        a1.IDNbr, 
                        a2.CustName, ' + @months + ',
                        AVG(a1.Balance) as Balance
                    FROM tlbID a1 
                    INNER JOIN tblCust a2 ON (a1.IDNbr = a2.IDNbr)
                    WHERE a1.Balance != 0.00 
                      AND a2.CustType != ''Inactive''
                    GROUP BY 
                        a1.IDNbr, a2.CustName, CONCAT( CONVERT(nvarchar(15), YEAR(BalDate)) , IIF(LEN(MONTH(BalDate)) > 1, CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(BalDate)), ''0'' + CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(BalDate))))) as d1
PIVOT (
    AVG(Balance)
    FOR BalMonth IN (' + @Dates + ')
) piv';


EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynSQL
```

Comment: I've applied this exact code and still getting the error `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'BalDate'.`

Comment: does tblID have a column named BalDate?

Comment: Yes, 'tblID' has a column 'BalDate'.

Comment: Try the above pls

Comment: If you remove the `a1.BalDate` from the select statement, it works! Although, this is giving me just the normal records I already have. I'm needing percent difference based on the records I have

Comment: What is the error you're seeing without removing a1.BalDate? Also, if you're doing a GROUP BY, I think you need to have some AGG function in the SELECT.

Comment: The error was in the data-- the dates were returning the data. However, it was showing every day per month, as I'm only wanting the _average_ of the overall month, and then finding the percent different between the monthly averages

Comment: Try the above now pls. I think if we first want to get AVG of all the months, we need to get rid of a1.BalDate and aggregate (using AVG function) on the balance per month. I've done that now. Does that look better?

Comment: Yes, this is how I'm needing it to look. I'm now needing to get the percent difference of each month based on that stored procedure

Comment: Is it possible to get an example of `tlbID` and `tblCust` table schema + some data?

Comment: I could add an example, yes. Although I'm not sure that it'd be much help. `tblCust` is only used to match the `CustName` with the `IDNbr` and used in the `where` clause to see if Custs are `Inactive`. I have used `SET @PerDiff = 'SELECT IDNbr, CustName FROM (' + @DynSql + ') d1 '` and that ran just fine. I'm now just needing to figure out how to create, dynamically, the columns for the percent difference of the columns in `@DynSql`

Comment: Hmm, how do you want the percent difference, from the previous month? Also, adding an example of the code would make it so people can actually run your script and better help. Right now, I am just going off of what makes sense rather than seeing actual results.

Comment: Yeah, the percent should be from the previous month. I though I added a good example of what I have and what I'm needing, result wise. I've also altered the code to show what I'm currently using.